# Google Maps iOS SDK - Stop deselecting marker on map tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am adding a simple marker to my mapView, like so:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.763981, -73.971647);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker.map = self.mapView;
marker.snippet = @"My Marker";
self.mapView.selectedMarker = marker;
```

As you can see I select the marker upon placement, however I want to keep this marker selected, showing the infoview, at all times it is on the map.

Currently, if I tap elsewhere on the map, the infoview is hidden (but the marker stays)

Comment: I think that maybe you need use a custom markerView with the aspect of your marker selected

Comment: @AdamG what about keeping your selected marker as a global reference and on tap of map anywhere, in the respective delegates, again write this line `self.mapView.selectedMarker = marker;`